Screened subnet implementation and nat
I'm trying to implement a screened subnet but I don't know which is the right way to do it.
Is it correct to have both internal and external routers doing NAT (IP Masquerading), while internal one translates from private class-A IP to a private class-C IP, and the external one translates from a private class-C IP to a public IP?
The screened subnet (DMZ) has the class-C network IP and if an exposed host will be compromised, it cannot sniff any internal packets. Also, given the address translation performed by internal router, compromised host cannot discover any internal ip addresses.
For both routers I'll have to setup ACLs and other firewall rules.
If this is not the right pattern, can you help me to understand which is the best practice to implement a screened subnet firewall architecture?
Thank you in advance
